# How to attach existing fragment

Tags: android, fragment

How can I attach existing fragment, when change back tab in ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS?

```
class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.detach(fragment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify if your fragment was loaded previously in the fragment stack. Also could store all your used fragments to reuse it

```
    public void setFragment(Fragment fragmentInstance) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        Fragment oldFragmentInstance = fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.curr_fragment);

        boolean onlyAttach = false;
        List<Fragment> prevFragments = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .getFragments();
        for (Fragment fragment : prevFragments) {
            if (fragment == null) {
                continue;
            }

            if (fragment.getClass().equals(fragmentInstance.getClass())) {
                onlyAttach = true;
                fragmentInstance = fragment;
                break;
            }
        }

        fragmentTransaction.detach(oldFragmentInstance);

        if (onlyAttach) {
            fragmentTransaction.attach(fragmentInstance);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.curr_fragment,
                    fragmentInstance);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        try {
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I try this code, but got error `The method getFragments() is undefined for the type FragmentManager`

Comment: You're right, the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html) doesn't reflect this method, but in my v4 support library I have this method o_O

It works fine for my

Comment: Yes, I know that `getSupportFragmentManager()` is from v4 support library, but I try to use it too - same error:( Could you give your example with import?

Comment: Did you tried to update your v4 support library to the last version (v19)?